# android Kotlin retrofit2 gson проблема с объектами

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, gson

Делаю запрос на апи таким образом

```
 GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            datasource.sendOtp(phone)
        }
```

ретрофит

```
  @POST(".")
fun sendOtpAsync(@Body baseRequest: BaseRequest): Deferred<SendOtpResponse>
```

в моем datasource обрабатываю

```
 val newData = ApiService.sendOtpAsync(BaseRequest(Methods_SendOtp, data)).await()
```

Сервер мне отправляет такой вот ответ

```
{
"error": {
    "errorMessage": "OK",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "statusCode": 200
}}
```

но вместо обьъекта SendOtpResponse который должен получитсья в итоге  я получаю

```
 {"error":{}}
```

Но если в Deferred < SendOtpResponse> заменить на Deferred < JsonElement > то можно получить JsonElement через который с помощью .toString() вытянуть валидный json с нужными полями. но когда эту же строку с помощью Gson в объект SendOtpResponse то получаю null вместо всех полей

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
```

. Если снова перевести в строку то будет {"error":{}} вместо целого json

Помогите 2 день уже разбираюсь .
ниже настройки ретрофита

```
  val requestInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
            var url = chain.request()
                .url()
                .newBuilder()
                .build()
            val request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
                .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
                .url(url)
                .build()
            return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
        }
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(connectivityInterceptor)
            .build()
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.invoke())
            .build()
            .create(JustinApiService::class.java)
    }
```

Comment: Как выглядит класс SendOtpResponse и Error? Если имя свойств не совпадает с таковыми в json, то нужно добавить @SerializedName("...") для свойств. Кстати, с версии Retrofit 2.6 можно делать функции сервиса сразу suspend вместо CoroutineCallAdapterFactory, `suspend fun sendOtpAsync(@Body baseRequest: BaseRequest): SendOtpResponse`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon @SerializedName("...") на полях присутствуют и указаны правильнно.
Gson просто отказывается  делать с jsonа объект

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри включен ли прогард в build.gradle и если да, то проверь его содержимое на наличие исключений для пакета.

also: @Keep